# Crosswalk Error Request was denied by security?

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk

I´m working in a hybrid app using cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview plugin, in order to make request using SSL to servers with self signed certificates I use the cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate plugin.

The problem is that after updating cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview to the version 2.2.0, the app is not able to make these requests(a toast message is displayed saying "Request was denied for security").

Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in this git issue https://github.com/danjarvis/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate/issues/1

installl the cordova crosswalk plugin and crosswalk certificate

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --variable XWALK_VERSION="18+"

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate

edit the ../platforms/android/src/org/crosswalk/engine/XWalkCordovaClientCertRequest.java

returning null instead request.getKeyTypes() and request.getPrincipals() on lines 55 and 70.

so you can build and run the application.

Comment: Hi Patricia, actually i tried your way. but im getting this kind of error.error: cannot find symbol
        return request.getKeyTypes();
                      ^
  symbol:   method getKeyTypes()
  location: variable request of type ClientCertRequest .  So please sort out from this. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sethu Have you tried to edit the class mentioned ?
(../platforms/android/src/org/crosswalk/engine/XWalkCordovaClientCertRequest.java) returning null instead request.getKeyTypes() and request.getPrincipals().